# TikZ: inverted cone (similar to linked thread but different issue)

Tags: tikz-pgf

[How to draw a simple cone with height and radius with TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171169/how-to-draw-a-simple-cone-with-height-and-radius-with-tikz/171172#171172)

In the above thread, a cone was created.  However, if I invert the cone, the lines from the origin to the cone edges cuts through the cone.  This is not visually pleasing.  How can I get the line to only intersect the `(\pm 2, 3)` without going through ellipse opening?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (h) at (0, 3);
  \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);

  \draw (O) -- +(0, 4);
  \draw (O) -- +(3, 0);
  \draw (O) -- +(-3, 0);

  \fill[
  top color = gray!50,
  bottom color = gray!10,
  shading = axis,
  opacity = 0.25
  ]
  (h) ellipse[x radius = 2, y radius = 0.5];
  \fill[
  left color = gray!50!black,
  right color = gray!50!black,
  middle color = gray!50,
  shading = axis,
  opacity = 0.25
  ]
  (2, 3) -- (O) -- (-2, 3) arc[x radius = 2, y radius = .5, start angle = 180,
  end angle = 360];

  \draw (-2, 3) arc[x radius = 2, y radius = .5, start angle = 180,
  end angle = 360] -- (O) -- cycle;
  \draw[dashed] (-2, 3) arc[x radius = 2, y radius = .5, start angle = 180,
  end angle = 0];
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suppose what you want to do is find a line starting at the tip of the cone that is tangential to the ellipse.

So let's do the math. Let `r1` be the horizontal radius of the ellipse, and let `r2` be the vertical radius. Let `z` be the distance from the tip of the cone to the midpoint of the ellipse. We have the following situation:

[image]

Here, `O` is the origin, `P` is the tip of the cone, `S` is the point at which the line is tangential to the ellipse, `alpha` is the angle between the horizontal axis and the line segment `OS`, and the vector `v` is a normal vector of the ellipse at point `S`.

We want the vector `PS` to be perpendicular to the vector `v`. I've used LaTeX for the remainder of the math: (Unfortunately tex.stackexchange.com does not have LaTeX formulas enabled.)

[image]

Note that, interestingly, the required angle does not depend on `r2`! Curiously, the required angle is the angle of a triangle whose diagonal side has length `z`, and whose side opposite to the angle has length `r2`. There must be a simpler proof for this (using congruent triangles?). But it is already way after bedtime, so I'll leave that as an exercise :)

In your particular case, you have `r2 = 0.5` and `z = 3`. This gives `alpha = 9.594` degrees. This means you should draw a line from the tip of the cone to the point `(pm 2 * cos(9.594), 3 - 0.5 * sin(9.594))` = `(1.972, 2.91666)`, instead of to `(2, 3)` as you are doing right now.

This code should get you going:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\rx{2}    % horizontal radius of the ellipse
  \def\ry{0.5}  % vertical radius of the ellipse
  \def\z{3}     % distance from center of ellipse to origin

  \pgfmathparse{asin(\ry/\z)}
  \let\angle\pgfmathresult

  \coordinate (h) at (0, \z);
  \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);     
  \coordinate (A) at ({-\rx*cos(\angle)}, {\z-\ry*sin(\angle)});
  \coordinate (B) at ({\rx*cos(\angle)}, {\z-\ry*sin(\angle)});

  \draw[fill=gray!50] (A) -- (O) -- (B) -- cycle;
  \draw[fill=gray!30] (h) ellipse ({\rx} and {\ry});
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

A number of example outputs for different values of `rx` ,`ry`, and `z`.

[image]

Comment: (1.972, 2.8333) this point doesn't make contact with my ellipse.  Can post your latex code for your diagram?

Comment: just note that \pgfmathparse{asin(\ry/\z)}\let\angle\pgfmathresult  can be replaced by \pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{asin(\b/\h)

Comment: "... the required angle does not depend on r2"? Shouldn't it read "... does not depend on r1"?

Answer (score 3):

There is another solution to the problem using package `intersections`.  It can be easily shown that the vertical position of the cone tip `y'` and vertical position of tangent point on ellipse `y0` are easily connected to the vertical radius `ry` of ellipse as

```
y' * y0 = ry * ry
```

[image]

So, all you have to do is draw ellipse, the appropriate (red) line and find intersections as in the example below

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\rx{2}    % horizontal radius of the ellipse
\def\ry{0.5}  % vertical radius of the ellipse
\def\z{3}     % distance from center of ellipse to origin

\path[name path=ellipse] (0,\z) ellipse ({\rx} and {\ry});
\path[name path=horizontal] (-\rx,\z-\ry*\ry/\z) -- (\rx,\z-\ry*\ry/\z);
\path [name intersections={of = ellipse and horizontal}];

\draw[fill=gray!50] (intersection-1) -- (0,0) -- (intersection-2) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=gray!30] (0,\z) ellipse ({\rx} and {\ry}); 

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

to get this

[image]