# How to draw a cone with descriptions on it?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

**beamer** I would like to draw a cone in particular, with two descriptions like this:

[image: Cone]

I'm using beamer enviroment. 
I would like to know a code to allow do it. Curved lines can be replaced by arrow or something, the idea is to point the given names for the corresponding regions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[dashed, thick] (0,0) circle (2cm and 1cm);
\draw[line width=3pt]   (-2,0) -- (0,5) -- (2,0);
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (-2.5,\pgflinewidth) -- (2.5,\pgflinewidth) -- (2,-1.5) -- (-2,-1.5) --cycle;
\draw[line width=3pt] (0,0) circle (2cm and 1cm);
\end{scope}
\node at (-1,-2)(s){Sasaki-Einstein};
\draw[line width=2pt] (s) to[bend right] (1,-1);
\draw[line width=2pt] (2,4) node[above]{Calabi Yau}  |- (1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: To make a better look to a cone, here is an interesting an question and answer : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171561/tikz-inverted-cone-similar-to-linked-thread-but-different-issue